# Python LAN messenger notification

Tags: python, sockets, server, lan

I made a LAN messenger using Python. I want you to help me to make it so that when someone sends a message a notification sound is played. Here is the code, first for server and second for client.

```
from socket import *
import threading
import sys 

FLAG = False  


def recv_from_client(conn):
    global FLAG
    try:

        while True:
            if FLAG == True:
                break
            message = conn.recv(1024).decode()

            if message == 'q':
                conn.send('q'.encode())
                print('Closing connection')
                conn.close()
                FLAG = True
                break
            print('Client: ' + message)
    except:
        conn.close()



def send_to_client(conn):
    global FLAG
    try:
        while True:
            if FLAG == True:
                break
            send_msg = input('')

            if send_msg == 'q':
                conn.send('q'.encode())
                print('Closing connection')
                conn.close()
                FLAG = True
                break
            conn.send(send_msg.encode())
    except:
        conn.close()



def main():
    threads = []
    global FLAG


    HOST = 'localhost'


    serverPort = 6789


    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)


    serverSocket.bind((HOST, serverPort))


    serverSocket.listen(1)


    print('The chat server is ready to connect to a chat client')

    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    print('Sever is connected with a chat client\n')

    t_rcv = threading.Thread(target=recv_from_client, args=(connectionSocket,))
    t_send = threading.Thread(target=send_to_client, args=(connectionSocket,))


    threads.append(t_rcv)
    threads.append(t_send)
    t_rcv.start()
    t_send.start()

    t_rcv.join()
    t_send.join()



    print('EXITING')
    serverSocket.close()

    sys.exit()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
from socket import *
import threading
import sys


FLAG = False  # this is a flag variable for checking quit

# function for receiving message from client
def send_to_server(clsock):
    global FLAG
    while True:
        if FLAG == True:
            break
        send_msg = input('')
        clsock.sendall(send_msg.encode())

# function for receiving message from server
def recv_from_server(clsock):
    global FLAG
    while True:
        data = clsock.recv(1024).decode()
        if data == 'q':
            print('Closing connection')
            FLAG = True
            break
        print('Server: ' + data)

# this is main function
def main():
    threads = []
    # TODO (1) - define HOST name, this would be an IP address or 'localhost' (1 line)
    HOST = 'localhost'  # The server's hostname or IP address
    # TODO (2) - define PORT number (1 line) (Google, what should be a valid port number)
    PORT = 6789        # The port used by the server

    # Create a TCP client socket
    #(AF_INET is used for IPv4 protocols)
    #(SOCK_STREAM is used for TCP)
    # TODO (3) - CREATE a socket for IPv4 TCP connection (1 line)
    clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

    # request to connect sent to server defined by HOST and PORT
    # TODO (4) - request a connection to the server (1 line)
    clientSocket.connect((HOST, PORT))
    print('Client is connected to a chat sever!\n')



    # call the function to send message to server
    #send_to_server(clientSocket)
    t_send = threading.Thread(target=send_to_server, args=(clientSocket,))
    # call the function to receive message server
    #recv_from_server(clientSocket)
    t_rcv = threading.Thread(target=recv_from_server, args=(clientSocket,))
    threads.append(t_send)
    threads.append(t_rcv)
    t_send.start()
    t_rcv.start()

    t_send.join()
    t_rcv.join()

    print('EXITING')
    sys.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```